# Where is ruby used as a scripting engine?

Tags: ruby, scripting, scriptengine

This is a general research question. Where is ruby used (or usable) as a language for scripting inside a larger application. The goal is to see real-world examples.

So far the list includes:
1) Google Sketchup
2) Vim (some other text editors)

Comment: also should this be community wiki?

Comment: I didn't know they were using ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPG Maker Series!

Google it until i add info (on my phone, please excuse me)